# Since join guarantee order why we need synchronization in java

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I am pretty new to multithreading. I have 2 threads t1,t2. Each thread call count of integer for 1000 times. So finally output should be 2000.
If I use t1.join();t2.join(); it should return 2000.since join will ensure t2 will run after t1.

But why its not happening,if join ensures order why we need synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

join() does not start the thread (it is already started when you call join(), thus join can't "ensure order").. It waits for the thread to end. However, other threads can run while you are waiting for the thread to end.